# CORS Issues (IONIC 3)

Tags: ios, angular, http, cors, ionic3

I’m trying to handle with CORS issues in livereload mode, but I wasn’t able to find a reasonable solution for that. My backend was developed in Java and it’s running on localhost.

Command:

> ionic cordova emulate ios -l -c -s --address 127.0.0.1

ion.config.json:

```
{
  "name": "Smartmarket",
  "app_id": "",
  "type": "ionic-angular",
  "integrations": {
    "cordova": {}
  },
  "proxies": [{
        "path": "/SmartmarketWeb/endpoint",
        "proxyUrl": "http://127.0.0.1:8080/SmartmarketWeb/endpoint"
  }]
}
```

Request example:

```
let headers = new Headers({ 
    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
});
let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });
return this.http.post('http://127.0.0.1:8080/SmartmarketWeb/endpoint/login', json, options)
    .timeout(TIMEOUT_REQUEST*1000)
    .map(this.extractData)
    .do(this.logResponse)
    .catch(this.handleError);
```

Error:
[image]

Can anyone help me, please? I’ve tried to follow many solutions, however, none of them had an effect.

Comment: Its your server side not your client side that should be specifying the CORS headers

Comment: @Liam Thank you for your answer, but how does It work properly without using the livereload mode (in IOS simulator and real device)?

Comment: As @Liam points out the client side is not the place to specify the CORS headers. So you need to remove `'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
    'Access-Control-Allow-Methods': 'GET, POST, OPTIONS',
    'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials': true,
    'Access-Control-Allow-Headers': 'origin, content-type, accept'` from your request code. Adding those in your frontend JavaScript code isn’t going to have any effect other than to break things even further

Comment: You were right, I applied the solution on the server side and it worked indeed.

Answer (score 1):

> Workaround only - Not a perfect solution

---

I was running with the same problem, My ionic 3 app with ASP.net backend was working just fine, it was not working with IOS ( Iphone x - IoS 11 simulator ).

### Solution

I changed the `web view` option of my ionic app.

First, open config.xml and add the following properties

`<feature name="CDVWKWebViewEngine">
  <param name="ios-package" value="CDVWKWebViewEngine" />
</feature>
<preference name="CordovaWebViewEngine" value="CDVWKWebViewEngine" />`

Then remove all plugins and platforms then run or build your app

**Detailed steps given in [this url](http://uncaughterror.com/programming/ionic3/preflight-response-issue-with-ionic3-app-on-ios-build-only-resolved/)**

Comment: this is recommended solution. use native plugin

Answer (score 0):

The problem was on the server side. Follow the solution below (Java - Jersey 2):

Filter class:

```
@Provider
public class CORSResponseFilter implements ContainerResponseFilter {

    @Override
    public void filter(ContainerRequestContext requestContext, ContainerResponseContext responseContext) throws IOException {

        MultivaluedMap<String, Object> headers = responseContext.getHeaders();

        headers.add("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");    
        headers.add("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET, POST, DELETE, PUT");          
        headers.add("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "origin, content-type, accept, authorization");
        headers.add("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", "true");


    }

}
```

web.xml:

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>Endpoint</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>jersey.config.server.provider.packages</param-name>
        <param-value>com.smartmarket.endpoint</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
            <param-name>jersey.config.server.provider.classnames</param-name>
            <param-value>com.smartmarket.filter.CORSResponseFilter</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
```

Answer (score 0):

Best solution:

Option 1)

For ionic v2 or v3 : 
https://ionicframework.com/docs/v3/native/http/

For cordova/phonegap : 
https://github.com/silkimen/cordova-plugin-advanced-http

Option 2)

Enable CORS on server.